# RVM not reading .rvmrc files when I open a new tab in my terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rvmrc

`rvmrc` is getting called when I visit that folder using 'cd'. But when I'm opening it in new terminal using ctrl+shift+t, rvmrc is not getting loaded.

Here is some  more detail:

```
tech@pc113:~/workspace/apps$ type rvm | head -1
rvm is a function
-bash: type: write error: Broken pipe
tech@pc113:~/workspace/apps$
```

echo $PATH

```
/home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/tech/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/tech/.rvm/bin:/home/tech/.rvm/bin:/home/tech/.rvm/bin
```

echo $GEM_HOME

```
/home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
```

echo $GEM_PATH

```
/home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/home/tech/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global
```

which rake

```
/home/tech/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/rake
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post output of?  
`echo $PATH`  `echo $GEM_HOME`  `echo $GEM_PATH`  `gem env`  `which rake`